# Fill Textbox with Data from RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

When I click on an item I would like to fill my TextBox with numbers from a column from Grid2 after Grid1 is clicked. Right now if I click on an item in Grid1 it will then run a procedure that will fill Grid2 with data. Here is an example of the current functionality with picture attached, I click an item from Grid1 and it has 3 results, my textbox will still display as an empty textbox. Then I click another item in Grid1 and now my textbox will display the 3 results from the previously clicked item. How can I display the correct numbers in my textbox after an item is selected in Grid1.

I have tried a few different methods including:

```
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        divDetails.Visible = true;
        RadTextBox1.Text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Grid_Product_List_Details.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            RadTextBox1.Text += Grid_Product_List_Details.Items[i].GetDataKeyValue("number").ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }
```

and:

```
protected void Grid_Product_List_Details_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid grid = (RadGrid)sender;

    if (grid.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            RadTextBox1.Text = "";
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            RadTextBox1.Text += grid.Items[i].GetDataKeyValue("number").ToString() + "\n";
        }
    RadTextBox1.DataBind();

}
```

and this:

```
protected void Grid_Product_List_Header_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadTextBox1.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Grid_Product_List_Details.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        RadTextBox1.Text += Grid_Product_List_Details.Items[i].GetDataKeyValue("number").ToString() + "\n";
    }    
}
```

But those aren't working. Any suggestions?

[image: RadGrid Sample Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a procedure which fills the textbox after an item is clicked so the most recent data appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code a little bit.

> RadTextBox1.Text = "";
>
> foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in Grid_Product_List_Details.Items)
>
> {
>
> ```
>    RadTextBox1.Text += dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("number").ToString() + "\n";
> ```
>
> }
>
> RadTextBox1.DataBind();

This should work though I suspect your earlier code should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ItemDataBound event of the second grid. You will have access to all of its data so you can put that in the RadTextBox. I suspect you provide a data source to the second grid in the SelectedIndexChanged of the first, so its Rebind() method should be called and then you will get the ItemDataBound fired for each of its rows.

Also, if you are using AJAX - disable it. It is possible that something does not get properly updated with the partial rendering. If things work fine with full postbacks, examine the responses and see why the textbox is not included in the first request so you can know how to tweak your AJAX setup.